# 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException': Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying get records of a table satisfied some conditions but I received a

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

First, I created a DbCommand object called 'Command'.

```
var queryText = "CREATE VIEW T1 AS (SELECT SUM(TestTable.Id) AS [SUM TestTable.Id], TestTable.Name AS [TestTable.Name] FROM TestTable GROUP BY TestTable.Name );\nCREATE VIEW T2 AS (SELECT [TestTable.Name] FROM (SELECT TestTable.Name AS [TestTable.Name], Row_Number()  OVER(PARTITION BY TestTable.Name  ORDER BY TestTable.Name) AS row_number  FROM TestTable ) AS T WHERE T.row_number = 1);\nSELECT T1.[TestTable.Name], [SUM TestTable.Id] FROM T1, T2 WHERE T1.[TestTable.Name] = T2.[TestTable.Name] ";

var Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SONDHE;Initial Catalog=Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=K1nh#bang#te#the;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE";

var command = Database.Connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = queryText;
command.Connection = Database.Connection;
command.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

Then, I executed the command to get records:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    return reader.ToExpandoList();
}
```

but it throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'

But I ran this query in SQL Server and it executed successfully.

This is table `TestTable` in database `Test` in SQL Server. I hope someone can explain me. Thank you!

Comment: Run it twice and see it go BOOM!.

Comment: remove the useless _\n_ between the three commands. The semicolon is enough to separate them. This query text is read by the database parser, it doesn't need to have the queries on separate lines.

Comment: You should **never** mix DDL (Data Definition Language - like  `CREATE VIEW`) with DML (Data Manipulation Language - like `SELECT`) in a single statement !

Comment: You should study a lot more and try a little harder before submitting questions to StackOverflow. This place is not intended to be a replacement for the most basic development skills. That said, you are trying to do a lot of things in the same query. Did you try and split them into 3 separate commands, each with its own query? The "Create View" queries should be run with command.ExecuteNonQuery() instead of command.ExecuteReader(). I only didn't downvote you because it's your first question. Try harder.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW` must be the only statement in the batch. You cannot execute a single batch with multiple create view statements (or any other statements). Use separate `ExecuteNonQuery` commands for each view and then `ExecuteReader` for the `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the words `CREATE VIEW` with the word `WITH` and remove the semicolon